# Why jest document.createElement('div') and other elements are empty when calling console.log?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, console.log

Why my html variables are always empty when jest is running? When I directly print them by accessing the `innerHTML` variable, the contents are there, but why they do not show up when calling `JSON.stringify(obj)`? How can I correctly print them for debugging?

**reviewer.test.js**

```
test('renders test site', () => {
    const things = document.createElement('div');
    things.id = "things";
    things.innerHTML = '<div>some.</div>';
    console.log('things', things)
    console.log('things', JSON.stringify(things))

    document.body.appendChild(things);
    console.log('document.body', document.body)
    console.log('document.body', JSON.stringify(document.body))

    document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="test"><div class="panel-block"></div>....</div>';
    console.log('document.body', document.body)
    console.log('document.body', JSON.stringify(document.body))
});
```

```
$ npx jest

 PASS  src/reviewer.test.js
  √ renders test site (31ms)

  console.log src/reviewer.test.js:19
    things HTMLDivElement {}

  console.log src/reviewer.test.js:20
    things {}

  console.log src/reviewer.test.js:23
    document.body HTMLBodyElement {}

  console.log src/reviewer.test.js:24
    document.body {}

  console.log src/reviewer.test.js:27
    document.body HTMLBodyElement {}

  console.log src/reviewer.test.js:28
    document.body {}

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.358s
Ran all test suites.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^25.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not Jest. DOM elements cannot be converted to string using `JSON.stringify()`, you could use [domJSON](https://azaslavsky.github.io/domJSON/) for example if you want the full object of the element. If you just want to log the contents, then `console.log("things", JSON.stringify(things.outerHTML))` should work.

```js
const things = document.createElement("div");
things.id = "things";
things.innerHTML = "<div>some.</div>";
console.log("things", things);
console.log("things", JSON.stringify(things.outerHTML))
console.log("things", domJSON.toJSON(things));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/domjson@0.1.2/dist/domJSON.min.js"></script>
```

Potentially you could also use [console.dir()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)

Comment: How can I import this `domJSON` in my jest tests? After installing it with `npm install domjson --save-dev` I tried importing it with `const domJSON = require('domjson')`, but it is throwing this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined`

Comment: I think for this case, `console.log("things", JSON.stringify(things.outerHTML))` might be enough. You'll have to debug that, from the error message is hard to see why that is happening.